# Have user follow/take course - my method is wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am getting an rspec error when I have a user try to take/follow a course. I believe there must be something wrong with my method because it returns nil in the rspec test.  There is also an assignment model between the course and user models.  What is wrong?

The Error

```
 1) User taking course 
 Failure/Error: it { should be_taking_course(course)}
   expected taking_course?(#<Course id: 1, title: "Ze Finance Course 1", description:     "Description for course 1", typeof: nil, created_at: "2013-06-25 21:38:24", updated_at: "2013-06-25 21:38:24">) to return true, got nil
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:125:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :assignments, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :assignments

 def taking_course?(course)
   assignments.find_by_course_id(course.id)
 end

 def take_course!(course)
  assignments.create!(course_id: course.id)
 end

end
```

User spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

before(:each) do
 @attr = {
  :name => "Example User",
  :email => "user@example.com",
  :password => "changeme",
  :password_confirmation => "changeme"
  }

 end

describe "taking course" do
let(:course) {FactoryGirl.create(:course)}
before do
  @user = User.new(@attr)
  @user.save
  @user.take_course!(course)
end

it { should be_taking_course(course)} //this is the problem test

 end

 end
```

Answer (score 0):

`it { should ... }` is shorthand `it { subject.should ... }` but you are not setting up an `@user` rather than the `subject`. So RSpec will create an implicit `subject` which is just `User.new`.

You can probably fix your test by setting an explicit `subject` in much the same way you set up `@user`:

```
describe "taking course" do

  let(:course) {FactoryGirl.create(:course)}
  subject { User.create(@attr) }
  before do
    subject.take_course!(course)
  end

  it { should be_taking_course(course) }

end
```

If you don't want to do that then make your assertion more explicit:

```
  it { @user.should be_taking_course(course) }
```